# What is the statistic analysis for using small population data to represent larger population?

Tags: statistics

I want to know the name of the statistic analysis for small population data to represent larger population. E.g. TV will count 20% of total vote of US president election and tell statistically one of the candidate win. What is the statistic analysis name?

Comment: Survey sampling perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

[Confidence Interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval). It gives you the margin of error when estimating the frequency of a given caracter within a population by looking at a small sample. One of the interesting things about it is that it usually depend only on the size of the sample, and not on the size of the total population.